# How can we calculate Amritha kalam and varjyam in panchangam?

Tags: astrology, panchang

I want to calculate Amritha kalam and varjyam for Panchang.
Please help me for calculating those by providing any formulas.

Thanks in advance and be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly need to understand the Method to Calculate Chaughadia Muhurats

First each day is divided into two time periods:

1. day time (Din-maan) - the period from local sunrise to sunset
2. night-time (Ratri-maan) - the period from sunset to sunrise (next day)

Each time period contains eight Chaughadias. To calculate the duration of each Chaughadia, the respective time period is divided by eight to get 8 chaughadias of equal time. Since there are only 7 types of chaughadias, therefore, in each time period six Chaughadias get 1 division each in their share while one Chaughadia gets 2 divisions.

The Chaughadias are assigned to 8 equal divisions of each time period (day time or night time)  in a pre-determined order according to the weekday. The sequence of day-time and night-time Chaughadias varies for each week day. However, the sequence is fixed and does not change for each week day. For example, the sequence for Monday is different to that for Tuesday, which in turn is different to that for Wednesday. But the sequence for each Monday is the same, as also  for each Tuesday.  [Study the Tables Below]

Clearly, the 16 time divisions of 24 hours are assigned to 7 types of Chaughadias. There will be at least two Chaughadias of the same type within 24 hrs. and two types of  Chaughadias are repeated three times within 24 hrs.

The seven types of Chaughadias are as follows:

```
 Chaughadia       Ruled by               Nature



    1. Udwega      

    2. **Amrit**           

    3. Roga           

    4. Laabh           

    5. Shubh                

    6. Chara               

    7. Kaala
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ShreeM

Answer (score 0):

Varjyam basically depend on the Nakshatra of the day and its duration.

**Starting time of Varjyam = A×DurationOfNakshatra/60**

(A = a fixed number for each nakshatra. Example Aswini Nakshatra A = 50)

**DurationOfVarjyam = DurationOfNakshatra/15**

A = 50,4,30,40,14,21,30,20,32,30,20,1,21,20,14,14,10,14,20,20,20,10,10,18,16,30,30 respectively as per the sequence of nakshatras.